# send reset password template to gmail, outlook and anothers in django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I am able to send the password reset page and reset the password normally, but only by gmail, if you put EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
I can send to outlook, but how can I send to all valid emails? (outlook, gmail ...)

because like '' smtp-mail.outlook.com '' and 'smtp.gmail.com', I can only send to one or the other, never both

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'emailHere'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'passwordHere'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: That doesnt make sense, You can't send an email without the provider's SMTP, there no service that combines them all, Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: I thought `EMAIL_HOST` was your email provider not the email provider of the recipient.

Comment: this is what I wanted, to know if there was one that sent to everyone, but I understood now, would I have to hire some smtp server?